# Angular $http file Post

Tags: php, json, angularjs, post

It's been a while now that I'm struggling with an Angular $http request. The point is that I'm trying to post some data to an API, here's the code:

```
var data = [
    {name: 'method', value: 'createtab'},
    {name: 'title', value: $scope.newTile.title},
    {name: 'upload', value: $scope.newTile.video}
];

data = JSON.stringify(data);

$http({
    url : "/api/",
    method: "POST",
    data : data,
    iframe: true,
    pocessData: false
}).success(function(message, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //etc..
}
```

This is working fine, unless the size of the video I'm uploading is bigger than 9MB. Any ideas? I think the problem is the JSON parsing, therefore a normal POST request might do the job; I tried to do that, but I couldn't manage to make it work... Did anybody face a similar problem?

Comment: I think it may be related to configuration of server

Answer (score 0):

You should check your server's configuration and change two variables

These variables can be set in several places. For example in php.ini, .htacess or in application by `ini_set()` function.

**php.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

**.htaccess**

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

**ini_set()**

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
ini_set('post_max_size ', '100M');
```

100M means 100 mega bytes